# Mapbox-gl-js "nested" Interior-Polygons not displaying

Tags: mapbox, geojson, mapbox-gl-js

I have a geoJson-structure that looks like this:

[image]

Where the array at the 0 position is the exterior Polygon and the array at position 1 ist the interior Polygon. To style the polygons I add these layers:

```
{'id': dist.identifier,
      'type': 'fill',
      'source': dist.identifier,
      'layout': {},
      'paint': {
        'fill-opacity': 0.3,
        'fill-color': "#ffff00",
      }
}
//and
{
      'id': `${dist.identifier}-line-layer`,
      'type': 'line',
      'source': dist.identifier,
      'layout': {},
      'paint': {
        'line-width': 3,
        'line-color': '#ffff00'
      }
    }
```

The output looks like this:

[image]

And when I zoom in:

[image]

I would expect to see something like this:
https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeoJSON#/media/Datei:SFA_Polygon_with_hole.svg

But the interior Polygon is not showing up. Am I doing something wrong, as this should be the valid geoJson Structure (https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeoJSON). I looked at the layer definitions but didn't find anything regarding interior Polygons.

I'd appriciate all input and thank you in advance!

### Edit:

Thanks to @Steve Bennet who pointed me to the this lint tool: https://geojsonlint.com/

I found out that I

A: An interior Polygon should follow the right hand rule: https://mapster.me/right-hand-rule-geojson-fixer/

B: It has to have at least 4 Points where start and end are the same

and C: The interior Polygons were not correctly nested in the coordinates array

Comment: Could you share the geojson file?? By itself it should be visible in any GitHub repo [like this one](https://github.com/jscastro76/threebox/blob/master/examples/geojson/extrusion.geojson) in my repo

Comment: You should use https://geojsonlint.com/ to verify its structure.

Comment: @jscastro and interesting, I didn't know about that feature of Github. I am generating it on the fly but I will try this and get back with the result. Then I will lint the structure Thank you for your responses!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Steve Bennet (see comments) who pointed me to the this lint tool: https://geojsonlint.com/

I found out that I

A: An interior Polygon should follow the right hand rule: https://mapster.me/right-hand-rule-geojson-fixer/

B: It has to have at least 4 Points where start and end are the same

and C: The interior Polygons were not correctly nested in the coordinates array